# Ionic2 - LiveReload not working

Tags: android, angular, npm, ionic2, cordova-plugins

I'm trying to run a brand new `Ionic2` application on my `Android` device with `--livereload` option but I'm getting errors.

Setup commands:

```
$ ionic start ionic2-speed-test-run --v2
$ cd ionic2-speed-test-run/
$ cordova platform add android
```

If I do:

```
$ ionic run android
```

The application runs properly on my `Android` device, but if I do:

```
$ ionic run android -l
```

Then I get the followin error output:

```
$ ionic run android -l

> ionic-hello-world@0.0.0 ionic:serve D:\ionic2\ionic2-speed-test-run
> ionic-app-scripts serve "--v2" "--runLivereload" "--isPlatformServe" "--livereload" "--port" "8101" "--livereload-port" "35730" "--address" "192.168.1.202" "--iscordovaserve" "--nobrowser"

[17:37:09]  ionic-app-scripts 1.3.0
[17:37:09]  watch started ...
[17:37:09]  build dev started ...
events.js:160
      throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
      ^

Error: listen EADDRINUSE 0.0.0.0:53703
    at Object.exports._errnoException (util.js:1018:11)
    at exports._exceptionWithHostPort (util.js:1041:20)
    at Server._listen2 (net.js:1262:14)
    at listen (net.js:1298:10)
    at net.js:1408:9
    at _combinedTickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:83:11)
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:104:9)
    at Module.runMain (module.js:606:11)
    at run (bootstrap_node.js:393:7)
    at startup (bootstrap_node.js:150:9)

npm ERR! Windows_NT 10.0.14393
npm ERR! argv "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "run" "ionic:serve" "--" "--v2" "--runLivereload" "--isPlatformServe" "--livereload" "--port" "8101" "--livereload-port" "35730" "--address" "192.168.1.202" "--iscordovaserve" "--nobrowser"
npm ERR! node v6.10.2
npm ERR! npm  v3.10.10
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! ionic-hello-world@0.0.0 ionic:serve: `ionic-app-scripts serve "--v2" "--runLivereload" "--isPlatformServe" "--livereload" "--port" "8101" "--livereload-port" "35730" "--address" "192.168.1.202" "--iscordovaserve" "--nobrowser"`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the ionic-hello-world@0.0.0 ionic:serve script 'ionic-app-scripts serve "--v2" "--runLivereload" "--isPlatformServe" "--livereload" "--port" "8101" "--livereload-port" "35730" "--address" "192.168.1.202" "--iscordovaserve" "--nobrowser"'.
npm ERR! Make sure you have the latest version of node.js and npm installed.
npm ERR! If you do, this is most likely a problem with the ionic-hello-world package,
npm ERR! not with npm itself.
npm ERR! Tell the author that this fails on your system:
npm ERR!     ionic-app-scripts serve "--v2" "--runLivereload" "--isPlatformServe" "--livereload" "--port" "8101" "--livereload-port" "35730" "--address" "192.168.1.202" "--iscordovaserve" "--nobrowser"
npm ERR! You can get information on how to open an issue for this project with:
npm ERR!     npm bugs ionic-hello-world
npm ERR! Or if that isn't available, you can get their info via:
npm ERR!     npm owner ls ionic-hello-world
npm ERR! There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
npm ERR!     D:\ionic2\ionic2-speed-test-run\npm-debug.log
```

Just in case, environment info here:

```
$ ionic info

Your system information:
Cordova CLI: 6.5.0
Ionic Framework Version: 3.0.1
Ionic CLI Version: 2.2.2
Ionic App Lib Version: 2.2.1
Ionic App Scripts Version: 1.3.4
ios-deploy version: Not installed
ios-sim version: Not installed
OS: Windows 10
Node Version: v6.10.2
Xcode version: Not installed
```

Any idea on how to make the `--livereload` works?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This type of error happens when you are **already using live-loading** with same ip address. just kill other running ionic apps and try your luck.

if you still get this error just **restart system** and try it again.

last but least

**upgraded my cordova and ionic** to latest versions then its working great. just treat it as last hope.

i have used last option for my ionic app.

Comment: Intead of restarting the system, just kill all node processes.

Answer (score 0):

This message happen when live reload url already in use. Might be you are running `$ ionic serve` command and try to `$ ionic run android -l` Close all running program and try again. If problem not resolve, try with restart you system. It will forcefully close your all application. You may try with downgrade Ionic to version 2.